# Why i can't receive messages in strophe js?

Tags: javascript, strophe

I have this code.I send messages to server but i don't receive them.I have code from a post where the user say is working.I have a xmpp server where i can connect with strophe.

```
    <html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="strophe.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="init">
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    BOSH_SERVICE = 'http://localhost:5280/http-bind/';
    xmpp_user = "user";
    xmpp_domain = "localhost";
    xmpp_userdomain = "user@localhost";
    xmpp_password = "secret";

    angular.
    module('myApp', []).
    controller('init', function(xmppAuth){
        xmppAuth.auth(xmpp_userdomain,xmpp_password);

        on_presence = function (presence){
            console.log('presence');
            return true;
        }

        on_message = function (message){
            //console.log('message');
            console.log(message);
            return true;
        }
    }).
    service('xmppAuth', function() {
        return {
            auth: function(login, password) {
               connect = new Strophe.Connection(BOSH_SERVICE);
               connect.connect(login, password, function (status) {
                   if (status === Strophe.Status.CONNECTED) {
                        console.log("Autentificare reusita!");

                        //try send helo
                        var message = "helo";
                        var to = "marian@localhost";
                        if(message && to){
                            var reply = $msg({
                                to: to,
                                type: 'chat'
                            })
                            .cnode(Strophe.xmlElement('body', message)).up()
                            .c('active', {xmlns: "http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates"});
                            connect.send(reply);
                            console.log('I sent ' + to + ': ' + message);
                        }

                        //addhandler receive messg
                        connect.addHandler(onMessage, null, "message", null, null, null);
                        var onMessage = function (message){
                            console.log('S-a primit un mesaj');
                            console.log('message');
                            return true;
                        }

                   }
               })
            }
        }
    })

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

What i should do?Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem and I noticed that setting the handler before sending any message would allow you to read the messages, even those you send.
Below is a working code which I have tested

...

```
server_connection.connect(user_id, password, function(status){
    if (status == Strophe.Status.CONNECTED){
          on_connected();
    }
 });



function on_connected(){ server_connection.addHandler(on_message, null, 'message');}

var on_message =  function(message){ /* work with message here */ }
```

Answer (score 0):

You won't receive messages which you send, only incoming messages, or use MUC plugin for history.